# What's the intention of waitpid

Tags: linux

The sample code below is from linux man page waitpid function. Can the last else if be replaced with else? When I write code, I would write like:if, else if, and end with else. So I think it is strange in the sample code.

```
   #include <sys/wait.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <stdio.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       pid_t cpid, w;
       int status;

       cpid = fork();
       if (cpid == -1) {
           perror("fork");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (cpid == 0) {            /* Code executed by child */
           printf("Child PID is %ld\n", (long) getpid());
           if (argc == 1)
               pause();                    /* Wait for signals */
           _exit(atoi(argv[1]));

       } else {                    /* Code executed by parent */
           do {
               w = waitpid(cpid, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
               if (w == -1) {
                   perror("waitpid");
                   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
               }

               if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
                   printf("exited, status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
               } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
                   printf("killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
               } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
                   printf("stopped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
               } else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) { /* can this be 
                                                   *replaced with else ???
                                                   */
                   printf("continued\n");
               }
           } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the question I think you are asking:

> Is it possible for `waitpid` to return a `status` such that none of
>   `WIFEXITED(status)`, `WIFSIGNALED(status)`, `WIFSTOPPED(status)`, or
>   `WIFCONTINUED(status)` returns nonzero?

The answer is almost certainly "no", and the [Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) implies as much without (unfortunately) explicitly saying it.

The UNIX standard says more [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html), and specifically does guarantee that one of those macros will return nonzero in certain cases. But Linux is not (necessarily) compliant to this standard.

**But** I think the best solution in code would be to have an `else` clause after those four options, and (depending on your application) take this to mean that the status is unknown. This could happen even if it's not the case now - maybe in some future version of Linux there is another kind of exit condition not covered here, and you don't want your code to crash in such a case.

The standard does seem to have evolved over time. For example, earlier versions didn't have the `WIFCONTINUED` case, and I also found some references online to a `WIFCORED` in some other systems. So it would be good to make your code flexible if you're concerned about it.